# What was the first FPS game with strafing?

Tags: gaming-history, first-person-shooter

What was the first FPS game that introduced strafing?

As far as I remember it was there in Duke Nukem 3D and Quake, which were my first encounter with PC games.

Comment: What is FPP? Do you mean FPS?

Comment: Specifically a character on foot, or are you including vehicular movement?

Comment: @Flater actually, is about the concept of first person perspective and side movement.

Comment: @DanubianSailor: There have been first person views from vehicles, most notably tanks and spaceships.

Answer (score 5):

I did some research, and my guess will be:

[Catacomb 3D](https://www.gog.com/forum/catacombs_pack/catacomb_3d_controls), a first-person shooter with a dark fantasy setting released in November 1991:

> I could try using the keymapper for W and S for cursor up and down, and A and D for **the strafe modifier** plus left and right cursor, so that they are **strafe left and right**.

Also from [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/o5chs/what_game_was_the_first_to_introduce_strafing_to/), another user kinda confirms to be *Catacomb 3D*.

---

[Gun Buster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_Buster_(arcade_game)), a arcade videogame released in August 1992:

> Gun Buster control scheme consists of a joystick for movement and **strafing** and a light gun for aiming and turning.

[Catacomb Abyss](https://forums.overclockers.co.uk/threads/project-first-person-shooter-history.18842661/page-2), a 1992 first person shooter:

> It controls with the arrows, with left and right turning rather than strafing. **Strafing requires you to hold alt**, and fire is ctrl.

Comment: Bear in mind that Wolfenstein 3D, which also came out in 1992, had the same strafe controls that Catacomb Abyss did

Comment: Both were developed by the same people.

Comment: @Powerlord my bad, totally forgot it. So we need to figure out which was developed first

Comment: Wolfenstein 3D appears to be based on Catacombs 3D prototype, since its development officially began on December 15, 1991 ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_3D#Development)).

Comment: I don't think "*I remember strafing in Catacomb 3D*" is a great source of authority. It's a random person saying they remember something on Reddit :D Besides, especially when it comes to video games I've misremembered things by mixing up games.

Comment: @Joachim uhm, right, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: [The game source code](https://archive.org/details/Catacomb3-D_source) references strafing, although I will admit that I don't see where they use it.